# How to prevent EventListener "keyup" react to "backspace" when string is empty?

Tags: javascript, search, keyup

I'm trying to set up 2 conditions:

```
userInput = document.getElementById("search")
userInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
 if ((e.target.value).length === 0 && e.keyCode === 8) {
   console.log("Fail again");
 } 
})
```

...and it's working fine at start. But you'll get "Fail again" when string.length === 1 and press "backspace" (deleting last symbol in search input).
Is anybody know some way to make it follow conditions? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

When there is 1 character and you press backspace, the input value is changed (empty), and then your `keyup` event triggers. Your conditions are met, so you see the message. If you want to know what the value is before the backspace has taken effect, use `keydown`.

Demo :

```js
userInput = document.getElementById("search")
userInput.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.target.value.length === 0 && e.keyCode === 8) {
    console.log("Fail again");
  } 
})
```

```html
<input id="search"/>
```

If you want to still be able to get the updated value inside the event listener, you could do something like this:

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("search");
let previousSearchValue = userInput.value;

userInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (previousSearchValue.length === 0 && e.keyCode === 8) {
    console.log("Fail again");
  }
  previousSearchValue = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input id="search"/>
```

Comment: In that case i'm kinda "1 step back" when user typing something...(((
Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Sergiy I added an alternative way using `keyup`

Comment: Uiiiiiiii......That is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.